# Bash script - How to only resize images not recently modified?

Tags: bash, image, shell, scripting

I have a bash script I am writing that will reduce all image file sizes in a given directory. The directories in which this will be executed in are dedicated to image uploads only on our server.

The way I did this so far is that the script will check all files in the directory specified in Argument 1 and see if the file is a directory or not. If it is not a directory, it will then proceed to reduce the file size using `magick -resize`.

However, I have run into two problems here. The first is that I don't want to resize images that have already been resized. The second problem is that I don't want to resize images that are already small. Can I tell the script to only resize images that were not recently modified? Is there a better safety measure against this? And how can I specify to only resize images bigger than certain dimensions (i.e 1024 x 968, etc.)? Forgive me if these have already been asked before. This is my first script and I was unable to find anything that specifically answered my questions without confusing me.

```
curr_dir=$1

for filepath in "$curr_dir"*
  do
      if [ ! -d "${filepath}" ]; then
          magick "$filepath" -resize 10% "$filepath"
          echo "$filepath has been reduced"
      else
          if [ -d "${filepath}" ]; then
          echo "$filepath is a directory and cannot be reduced."
          fi
      fi
  done
exit
```

Comment: I would have a think about what you are actually trying to achieve, because using a percentage for resizing seems suspect.... you want to reduce a 7,000 pixel wide image to 700, and a 400 pixel image to 40?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for getting back to me. The goal is to reduce image sizes on our site in order to reduce page loading speed. There's a few specific folders where images get uploaded and many of those pictures are huge, some let's say between 4,000px - 5,000px wide. But then there are many pictures that are much smaller that would be less than 800 px wide. Those are not really causing loading speed issues. There are far too many pictures located in these folders to go through one by one. Is there a better alternative to what I'm trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I tell the script to only resize images that were not recently modified?

Sure. If you can define the precise time span "recently".

> Is there a better safety measure against this?

If, for example, you only want to resize images that are bigger than 1024 x 968, *and* the result of resizing will make the image smaller than 1024 x 968, then the same image will never be resized again, because it will not match the requirements.

You can check the dimensions of an image using this command:

```
convert /path/to/image -format "%w %h" info:
```

This will print the width and height, separated by one space.

You could use this in your script like this, for example:

```
if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
    set -- $(convert "$filepath" -format "%w %h" info:)
    width=$1
    height=$2
    if ((width > 1024)) || ((height > 968)); then
        magick "$filepath" -resize 10% "$filepath"
        echo "$filepath has been reduced"
    else
        echo "$filepath is already small ($width x $height)"
    fi
else
    echo "$filepath is a not a file and cannot be reduced"
fi
```